# 2 issues on Jenkins - 1: open files are growing & 2: it’s faster when user is logged out

Tags: jenkins, ulimit

We’re encountering some issues in our Jenkins system:

1. We’ve noticed a continuous increase in the number of open files, and we’re actively investigating the root cause. As a temporary measure, we’ve raised the file limits to a higher threshold. While this addresses the immediate issue, we’re still working on pinpointing the source of the file leak.
2. We’ve observed that system performance is slower when a user is logged in. Surprisingly, when we log out and access different build logs, the system performs significantly better.

If any other have experienced similar issues or have insights to share, it’d be great. Thanks!

As a temporary measure we also restart the service and the node where it is setup which helps the service perform ok for a couple of days.

Comment: Please share your environment. Where do you run jenkins, which version, which java verion is installed in your VM or container. How many build your jenkins instance run? Also you could check jenkins logs while logged in "Manage jenkins" -> "System log"

Comment: @DmitriyTarasevich the logs don't say much on the open files. since we've increased the limit, it just keeps growing. But the slowness we couldn't find anything in the log. The version we're using is 2.342. And we're planning to upgrade.